# A regular surface is of measure zero

Tags: differential-geometry, lebesgue-measure, surfaces

Recall first the definition of a regular surface:

> A subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a **regular surface** if for every point $p\in S$, there is an open ball $B_r(p)$ around $p$ and an open set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and a continuously differentiable function $f:A\to S\cap B_r(p)$ such that $rank(Df) = 2$ and $f$ is surjective.

To my understanding, the notion that captures the fact that surfaces are '2 dimensional' in some intuitive sense, is the fact that $rank(Df) = 2$, and that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, so in some intuitive sense, the image of $f$ cannot be '3 dimensional'.

Given that, it should be quite intuitive that regular surfaces must be of measure zero ('2 dimensional' object in 3 dimensional world). I have had many failed attempts, including attempts to construct some Lipschitz function and to find some set of measure zero that will map to the surface (since Lipschitz functions preserve zero measure). Although intuitive, it seems non-trivial.

Comment: If you extend to $A \times \mathbb{R} \to B_r(p)$ by sending $(x, t)$ to $f(x) + t \mathbf{n}$ where $n$ is normal to $Df(x_0)$, I would expect that to be a local diffeomorphism with inverse image of $f$ being contained in $A \times \{ 0 \}$; which would allow you to apply the change of variables formula to get $S \cap B_r(p)$ of measure zero.  And then, since $S$ is Lindelof (as a subspace of a Lindelof metric space), you could choose a countable cover of $S$ by such open balls.

Comment: @Joshhh: You also need $f$ to be a diffeomorphism, surjective in particular. Otherwise the stated condition merely says $S$ contains the image of $A$ under an immersion, which of course does not imply $S$ has measure zero. :) <> Alternative to Daniel's strategy, it's possible to use the fact that a sufficiently small piece of a regular surface is the graph of a smooth function, then to cover $S$ by (at most) countably many such patches.